# LinQ datasource showing this error "LinqDataSource 'AirAsiaDC' has no values to insert. Check that the 'values' dictionary contains values"

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq

here is what i am trying to do, i am using LinQ data context to insert new record to database,
for some reason, my linq showing this error "LinqDataSource 'AirAsiaDC' has no values to insert. Check that the 'values' dictionary contains values." weird part, when i check the record which i tried to insert before, it is there. what i do wrong here?

by the way, here is my code :

```
protected void DetailsView1_ItemCommand(object sender, 
                                        DetailsViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    AirAsiaDCDataContext Linq = new AirAsiaDCDataContext();

    try
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "Edit")
        {
            TextBox tbname = (TextBox)DetailsView1.FindControl("DeptName");
            department dpt;

            if ((tbname.Text != null) && (tbname.Text != ""))
            {
                dpt = Linq.departments.Single(d => d.departmentcode == code);
                dpt.departmentname = tbname.Text;
                dpt.updateby = "hendra";
                dpt.lastupdate = DateTime.Now;
                Linq.SubmitChanges();
                Response.Redirect("Department.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                divError.Visible = true;
                lblError.Text = "Department name can not be empty";
            }
        }
        else if (e.CommandName == "Insert")
        {
            TextBox tbcode = (TextBox)DetailsView1.FindControl("DeptCode");
            TextBox tbname = (TextBox)DetailsView1.FindControl("DeptName");
            department dpt = new department();

            if (((tbcode.Text != null) && (tbcode.Text != "")) 
             && ((tbname.Text != null) && (tbname.Text != "")))
            {
                dpt.departmentcode = tbcode.Text;
                dpt.departmentname = tbname.Text;
                dpt.createby = "hendra";
                dpt.createdate = DateTime.Now;
                dpt.updateby = "hendra";
                dpt.lastupdate = DateTime.Now;
                Linq.departments.InsertOnSubmit(dpt);
                Linq.SubmitChanges();
            }
            else if ((tbcode.Text == null) || (tbcode.Text == ""))
            {
                divError.Visible = true;
                lblError.Text = "Department code can not be empty";
            }
            else if ((tbname.Text == null) || (tbname.Text == ""))
            {
                divError.Visible = true;
                lblError.Text = "Department name can not be empty";
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        divError.Visible = true;
        lblError.Text = ex.Message.ToString();
    }
}
```

i even try to use try and catch but get nothing, and my linq keep on showing that error and throw me to error screen.

Comment: Where this error happen? Edit or Insert? Please edit your code and show us where.

Comment: after this  Linq.SubmitChanges(); but try catch did not get any error message, and even it is an error, my record inserted to database, can't figure it out.

Comment: I believe the save have been committed. The error is related to the ASPX page. I suggest you check [this](http://raymondlittle.wordpress.com/2011/02/01/linqdatasource-has-no-values-to-insert/) or [this](http://instantdevelopment.blogspot.ch/2008/05/linqdatasource-error-on-update-or.html)